# proxy handler with deep nested objects

Tags: javascript, proxy

I want to make a proxy handler for any composite object. For example, an object like this (I want to handle function call):

```
let = obj {  
  a: {  
    b: {  
      c: callback => setTimeout(() => callback(null, 'hello'), 2000)  
    }  
  },  
  aa: {  
    bb: (callback, x, y) => setTimeout(() => callback(null, x + y), 40000)  
  }  
};
```

I made a simple handler, but it doesn't work with nested properties:

```
var handler = {
    get: function(target, name) {
        return typeof target[name] == 'function' ? 'function call' : target[name];
    }
}
```

I can a make handler to wrap each property in proxy. It works, but I think it is not the best way:

```
var handler = {
    get: function(target, name) {
        if (typeof target[name] == 'function') {
            return 'function call';
        }
        return typeof target[name] == 'object' ? new Proxy(target[name], handler) : target[name];
    }
}
```

Is there more efficient way to solve this problem?

```js
var obj = {  
  a: {  
    b: {  
      c: callback => setTimeout(() => callback(null, 'hello'), 2000)  
    }  
  },  
  aa: {  
    bb: (callback, x, y) => setTimeout(() => callback(null, x + y), 40000)  
  }  
};


var handler = {
 get: function(target, name) {
  if (typeof target[name] == 'function') {
   return 'function call';
  }
  return typeof target[name] == 'object' ? new Proxy(target[name], handler) : target[name];
 }
}

var p = new Proxy(obj, handler);

p.a.b.c
```

Comment: Do you plan to actually do something with function props, or just return a string "function call"?

Comment: Yes, i want to handle it in future